# Laravel How to concat with Full name First name Middle Initial Last name

Tags: php, laravel

Whats the proper way for concat in full name
its three columns in the table the resident_fname resident_mi resident_lname

```
$resident = Resident::whereRAW("Concat(resident_fname,'',resident_mi,'',resident_lname) LIKE '%{$request->input('reservation_name')}%'")
        ->first();
```

Comment: The answer only has fname and lname how about with three columns? including middle initial to make it a full name?

Comment: The SQL CONCAT function can be called with arbitrary many arguments.

Comment: @ginabotlola What are you trying to do here with concat?

Answer (score 0):

We need to Use CONCAT_WS() with raw query.but also know about CONCAT(). so why we use CONCAT_WS() ?

Both CONCAT() and CONCAT_WS() functions are used to concatenate two or more strings but the basic difference between them is that CONCAT_WS() function can do the concatenation along with a separator between strings, whereas in CONCAT() function there is no concept of the separator.

example:

```sql
mysql> Select CONCAT('Akash','is','a','good','developer') AS 'Example of CONCAT()';

+---------------------+
| Example of CONCAT() |
+---------------------+
| Akashisagooddeveloper   |
+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> Select CONCAT_WS(' ','Akash','is','a','good','developer') AS 'Example of CONCAT_WS()';

+------------------------+
| Example of CONCAT_WS() |
+------------------------+
| Akash is a good developer  |
+------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```php
$resident = Resident::where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", resident_fname, resident_mi, resident_lname)'), 'like', $request->input('reservation_name'))->first();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: When you are repeating the advice of a proposed duplicate link (that was recommended before you posted your answer), you should not answer -- you should flag/vote to close.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase i added some explanation as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

A better idea to create a function in model like

```
class Resident extends Model{
    public function name(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->middle_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```

and you can access it as

```
$resident = Resident::find(1);
$resident->name()
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems cleaner (less overhead)  to use pure sql for this task.

Comment: @mickmackusa  it is preference, if you will use a function, you can access it like model property, so why you will write a query? I have worked in various projects and eloquent is enough to do almost all jobs, which is more organised and easy for maintainability, so personally I don’t use any raw query in my apps.

Comment: Oh, I understand.  I am just trying to guess why the no-comment-down-voter hit you.

Comment: @mickmackusa  I think it is because they are thinking why I am answering a question which is marked as duplicate, what you guess?

Comment: No, the downvote (and neutralizing upvote) was before I hammered.  Regardless, my dupe link contains your advice (more or less).

Comment: @mickmackusa  but when I answered I think it was not marked as duplicate and I didn’t looked at that link, I just answered the question as normal at any cost I believe reporting question as duplicate is good but downvoting a correct answer without any comment is not good, if there is any answer similar to mine, people should point out that, but it is also preference I can not make any one bound.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am agree with you, in such cases without comment is really discouraging, and if there is a new user he will feel, what these people are doing, anyway there is a cause for making vote anonymous and I also respect that.